# In ansible playbook, how skip task if file already exist in block task?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a task like this :

```
- name: install jetbrains toolbox
changed_when:
block:
  - name: download toolbox
    get_url:
      url: 'https://download.jetbrains.com/toolbox/jetbrains-toolbox-{{ toolbox_version }}.tar.gz'
      dest: /tmp/toolbox.tar.gz
  - name: open toolbox
    unarchive:
      src: /tmp/toolbox.tar.gz
      dest: /opt/jetbrains-toolbox
args:
  creates: /opt/jetbrains-toolbox
```

But it yields an error : `ERROR! 'changed_when' is not a valid attribute for a Block`

How can I skip the download download of `/opt/jetbrains-toolbox.tar.gz` skip the download if `/opt/jetbrains-toolbox` is already there ?

Comment: See [checksum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#parameter-checksum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```yaml
---
- name: register status of /tmp/toolbox.tar.gz
  stat:
    path: /tmp/toolbox.tar.gz
  register: toolbox_path

- name: install jetbrains toolbox
  # check if toolbox_path is a regular file
  when: "not toolbox_path.stat.exists"
  block:
    - name: download toolbox
      get_url:
        url: "https://download.jetbrains.com/toolbox/jetbrains-toolbox-{{ toolbox_version }}.tar.gz"
        dest: /tmp/toolbox.tar.gz

    - name: open toolbox
      unarchive:
        src: /tmp/toolbox.tar.gz
        dest: /opt/jetbrains-toolbox
```

You might also want to include checksums in the download as you know the exact version you want to download.

Comment: They provide a checksum as well. Thanks ill try it, and if it works ill accept your answer

Comment: The system I'm on isn't properly setup and runs on Windows. I just created a bunch of Linux boxes to test on and the code needed a little fix. I'll edit the post and it should work that way. I changed the condition to `not toolbox_path.stat.exists`.

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineGuillaume did it work for you?

Comment: Didn't check yet ! looking at this tomorrow

Comment: @pierre-antoine-guillaume if it worked, please accept the answer; otherwise please note that it didn't

Comment: it works if I de-indent register: toolbox_path 1 time

Comment: OK. I fixed that thank you.